# How to save a DataFrame as a csv-file using pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, export-to-csv

Why does this approach not work?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('session').getOrCreate()
df = spark.range(5).toDF("index")
filepath = r"C:/my_favorite_directory"
df.write.csv(filepath)
```

---

**Update**

The above code works fine, the problem was that I had not specified the hadoop binary path to refer to the winutils binary, which is needed by pyspark to write csv-files.

Comment: Can you provide what exact errors you are getting

Comment: _Why does this approach not work?_ What happens?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunatly the error message is to long to fit in the question's body (only 30k characters are allowed)

Comment: You can provide the last 10-15lines of error

Answer (score 0):

Your filepath should ends with .csv or file extension. You are providing directory thats wrong

Comment: Thanks for your response. Refering to a file instead of a directory does not solve the problem.